# How do I get PropertyChanged events to bubble up?

Tags: silverlight, inotifypropertychanged

I have a hierarchy of objects (objects A, B), each of which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` such that...

A has a member of type B,
B has a member of C, C is of type bool

When C changes, its `PropertyChanged` event gets fired, however this does not fire B's property changed event. And therefore A does not react to B's change.

Is there a good way to bubble this up?

Answer (score 0):

This is great - I have to spend some more time looking at it. Thank you.

I found a different solution but it's a bit of a hack. I just set my binding path property to the nested type. Using my example above, in my xaml (which has a DataContext of object A) I set my binding as...

{Binding Path=B.C}

Bubbling the event up is definitely more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simplistic solution but can't you just subscribe to the PropertyChanged event  and propagate the call?

E.G.

```
MyContainedObject.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
```

and then in your handler:

```
private void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
}
```

This works great when your objects have properties with the same name. If you have properties with different names you will have to do a bit more work to convert between the property values.

```
private void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.PropertyName)       
    {         
     case "Property1":   
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ADifferentProperty1");
        break;                  
     case "Property2":            
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ADifferentProperty2");
        break;                   
     default:            
        this.OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);           
        break;      
   }
}
```